# Replacing ArrayList with List<> in C#

Tags: c#

I am using extensively ArrayList and having difficulty to use this List<>. I am using the EntitySpace ORM for doing DAL stuff. This thing works nicely BUT the issue is that I have to defined List<> with type of object which is complaining that it can't convert that.

I am appreciate your help.

Original using ArrayList:

```
public ArrayList Get()
    {
        TndCustomerTendersCollection collection = new TndCustomerTendersCollection();
        collection.Query
        .Select
        (
            collection.Query.CustomerTenderID,
            collection.Query.CustomerTenderID,
            collection.Query.CustomerTenderCode,
            collection.Query.CustomerTenderName,
            collection.Query.StartDate,
            collection.Query.DueDate,
            collection.Query.CompleteDate,
            collection.Query.DateCreated,
            collection.Query.LastDateModified
        )
        .Where
        (
            collection.Query.IsActive.Equal(true)
        );

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList ();
        foreach (TndCustomerTenders item in collection)
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

After replacing with List

```
public List<Tender> Get()
    {
        TndCustomerTendersCollection collection = new TndCustomerTendersCollection();
        collection.Query
        .Select
        (
            collection.Query.CustomerTenderID,
            collection.Query.CustomerTenderID,
            collection.Query.CustomerTenderCode,
            collection.Query.CustomerTenderName,
            collection.Query.StartDate,
            collection.Query.DueDate,
            collection.Query.CompleteDate,
            collection.Query.DateCreated,
            collection.Query.LastDateModified
        )
        .Where
        (
            collection.Query.IsActive.Equal(true)
        );

        // HOW DO CONVERT THAT TO THAT LIST

        List<Tender> list = new List<Tender>();
        foreach (TndCustomerTenders item in collection)
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Does TndCustomerTenders extend Tender? Because in the second example, you have a list of Tender objectss, not of TndCustomerTenders. To convert what you have above, you'd use List<TndCustomerTenders>

Comment: Should List<Tender> not be List<TndCustomerTenders>?

Comment: Shouldn't your foreach loop be: foreach (Tender item in collection)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TndCustomerTenders and Tender are two different types.

You need to either explicitly convert from TndCustomerTenders to Tender, or you need to define an implicit conversion.

```
List<Tender> list = new List<Tender>();
        foreach (TndCustomerTenders item in collection)
        {
            //assumes conversion via constructor
            list.Add(new Tender(item));
        }
```

or

```
List<Tender> list = new List<Tender>();
        foreach (TndCustomerTenders item in collection)
        {
            Tender t = new Tender() { foo = item.foo, bar = item.bar };
            list.Add(t);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
public List<Tender> Get()
```

to

```
public List<TndCustomerTenders> Get()
```

and change

```
List<Tender> list = new List<Tender>();
```

to

```
List<TndCustomerTenders> list = new List<TndCustomerTenders>();
```

Or if you are using the latest framework,

```
var list = new List<TndCustomerTenders>();
```

Comment: I want the output as Tender because that is what I defined in mt BUsiness objects while TndCustomerTenders is the object coming from DAL.

Answer (score 2):

```
return collection.ToList<Tender>();
```

Comment: Cool. Didn't know ToList had a generic means of doing this.

Comment: That assumes that TndCustomerTendersCollection offers the ToList() (which it may not) and two, the there exists a conversion between Tender and TndCustomerTenders

Comment: That collection offers NO ToList() method unfortunetly.

Comment: ToList<>() is an extension method which you automatically get when you put using System.Linq; in your code file.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
.Where(collection.Query.IsActive.Equal(true)).Cast<Tender>().ToList()
```

Comment: Unfortunetely, the collection that I have doesn't have that methods above.